# NSPredicate that can find an object and search attributes of the that object

Tags: ios, core-data, nspredicate

[image]

The following finds all Master objects with Master.nameLast equally a passed in string.  Though I want the NSPredicate to check if the object matches Master.nameLast and if this object has Master.batting.ab > 0

```
- (NSFetchedResultsController *)fetchedResultsController {

    if(_fetchedResultsController != nil) {
        return _fetchedResultsController;
    }

    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    NSManagedObjectContext *context = [self managedObjectContext];
    NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Master" inManagedObjectContext:context];
    [fetchRequest setEntity:entity];

    NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"debut" ascending:YES];

    NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"nameLast = [c]%@", nameLast];
    [fetchRequest setPredicate:predicate];

    NSArray *sortDescriptors = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:sortDescriptor, nil];
    fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = sortDescriptors;

    _fetchedResultsController = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest managedObjectContext:context sectionNameKeyPath:nil cacheName:nil];

    return _fetchedResultsController;
}
```

I want something that finds all Master objects matching the passed in string and have Master.batting.ab > 0

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(nameLast = [c]%@) AND (ANY batting.ab > 0)", nameLast];
```

Comment: try to  CONTAINS[cd] instead of [c]

Comment: nameLast = [c]%@ works fine.  I need the 2nd part of the predicate to also check if the object Master.batting.ab > 0

Comment: try this "Master.batting.ab.length >0 "

Comment: You will want to reverse those for performance.  Doing string compares is extremely slow compared to the numeric comparison.